# Undefined property in cakePHP shell

Tags: shell, cakephp, properties, console

This is the first time I use CakePHP shell, and I don't understand my errors:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/da5ui.png]

> Undefined property: CommandListShell::$command in [path]\lib\Cake\Console\Shell.php

I just opened a cmd and set my path to my project, and type "cake"

Thank you

Comment: can you try to execute Console\cake from folder app\

Comment: This is what I did to get this error

Comment: in the image it looks like you where in the Console\ folder